# Why does the same line of code fail sporadically?

Tags: python, stock

I love the wallstreet.py package to pull some solid data on options. If I pull a single piece of data, ~100% of the time it comes back like I expect.

However, when my list grows it becomes a bit flakey, fails on some data pulls, and may or may not get back on track. Below you can see when I run the same code in a loop, it goes well for ~20x, starts to fail a few times, and then gets back on track.

Any idea as to what is causing this and how I can fix it? Thanks!

**CODE:**

```
from wallstreet import Put

for i in range(0,100):
    print(i, Put('IWM', d=15, m=10, y=2021, strike=200))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
1 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
2 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
3 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
4 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
5 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
6 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
7 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
8 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
9 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
10 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
11 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
12 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
13 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
14 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
15 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
16 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
17 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
18 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
19 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
20 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
21 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
22 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
No options listed for given date, using 30-09-2021 instead
No option for given strike, using 199 instead
23 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=30-09-2021, strike=199)
No options listed for given date, using 30-09-2021 instead
No option for given strike, using 199 instead
24 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=30-09-2021, strike=199)
No options listed for given date, using 30-09-2021 instead
No option for given strike, using 199 instead
25 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=30-09-2021, strike=199)
No options listed for given date, using 30-09-2021 instead
No option for given strike, using 199 instead
26 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=30-09-2021, strike=199)
27 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
28 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
29 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
30 Put(ticker=IWM, expiration=15-10-2021, strike=200)
```

Comment: i think there should be `9` instead of `09` i guess...

Comment: Presumably the results depend on what the API is returning, since this is not stand-alone code.